# jQuery animations like slideDown and slideUp work great in browser but choppy on mobile phone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Like the title says, I made a mobile version of a site, and I tried using accordion style accompanied with jQuery to animate the elements sliding the accordion up and down, revealing and hiding the content.

Now my problem is that its really choppy and laggy on mobile phones but works great on PC browsers.

Do you got any suggestions how i can increase performance?

Here is a jfiddle of the accordion and how I'm using it. Ignore the broken images. I just want to know how to increase the performance of the sliding, to make it smoother, but at the same time i want it to be responsive, that's why I am not using any fixed width anywhere.

This is just an example of how I'm using it, in my webpage the text inside the accordions is styled (if that is information that might be useful). Any help would be really appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/kLh8r294/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="novosti">
        <div class="accordion">
        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-1"><img class="banner_1" src="novosti_slike_mobile/likovni_programi_za_djecu_i_mlade_najva_mob.jpg" /></a>
            <div id="accordion-1" class="accordion-section-content">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-2"><img class="banner_1" src="novosti_slike_mobile/programi_pripreme_za_upise_najava_mob.jpg"/></a>
            <div id="accordion-2" class="accordion-section-content">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-3"><img class="banner_1" src="novosti_slike_mobile/likovni_programi_za_odrasle_najava_mob.jpg"/></a>
            <div id="accordion-3" class="accordion-section-content">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-4"><img class="banner_1" src="novosti_slike_mobile/uradi_sam_najava_mob.jpg"/></a>
            <div id="accordion-4" class="accordion-section-content">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
        <div class="accordion-section">
            <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#accordion-5"><img class="banner_1" src="novosti_slike_mobile/preporucujemo_najava_mob.jpg"/></a>
            <div id="accordion-5" class="accordion-section-content">
                <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>
            </div><!--end .accordion-section-content-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-section-->
        </div><!--end .accordion-->
        </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion .accordion-section-content').slideUp(1000).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).closest('.accordion-section-title');

        if(currentAttrValue.hasClass('active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        }else {
            close_accordion_section();

            // Add active class to section title
            currentAttrValue.addClass('active');
            // Open up the hidden content panel
            $('.accordion ' + currentAttrValue.attr('href')).slideDown(1000).addClass('open'); 
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
.accordion,
.accordion * {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.accordion {
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  border-radius: 3px;
  /*background:#f7f7f7;*/
}


/*----- Section Titles -----*/

.accordion-section-title {
  /*width:100%;*/
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  /*border-bottom:1px solid #1a1a1a;*/
  background-color: rgba(175, 132, 77, 0.4);
  transition: all linear 0.15s;
  text-align: center;
  /* Type */
  font-size: 12px;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #1a1a1a;
  color: #fff;
}

.accordion-section-title.active,
.accordion-section-title:hover {
  /*background:#4c4c4c;*/
  background-color: rgba(76, 76, 76, 0.4);
  /* Type */
  text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-section:last-child .accordion-section-title {
  border-bottom: none;
}


/*----- Section Content -----*/

.accordion-section-content {
  padding: 15px;
  display: none;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

body {
    max-width:800px;
    margin:auto;
    font-family:"Alamendro",Georgia;
    font-size:100%;
    background-image:url('../novosti_slike_mobile/pozadina_mob.jpg');
    background-size: auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    /*background-repeat: no-repeat;*/
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```

Comment: A choppy animation probably means the phone doesn't have the processing power to render it smoothly, or there are too many other things happening on the phone at the same time.

Comment: @JimGarrison I hide all content and make it appear only when something is clicked on. All of the things on the mobile version of the page are just text and images. There is nothing running until it is clicked no other type of animation other then hide and appear content on the click of the button. And the accordion one. I tried it on a few different phones i get the same effect..